# Accessing values from a dictionary via a List selection in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swift-dictionary, swiftui-view

I am thinking that this is probably quite simple to fix but I’ve not been able to find a solution so far.

I am trying to display a dictionary and allow the user to select an item so that I then have programatic access to both the keys and the values of their selection

I am able to display both the keys and values when listing the dictionary - e.g.

```
Text("Key:\t\t\(item)\t\t\t")
Text("Value:\t\(myList[item] ?? "")”)
```

but when the user makes a selection I am only able to access the key and print it, not display via a Text view

```
print("Selection is:\($selection)")
```

Not:

```
Text("Selection is:\(selection)")
```

or

```
Text("Selection is:\($selection)")
```

I am thinking that this could be related to my setting the selection variable as:

```
@State private var selection = Set<String>()
```

I have tried to configure it as:

```
@State private var selection = Set<String:String>()
```

but get error meessages for this.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Full code is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var myList = ["Chumbawumba": "7", "Jini Dosa": "2", "Handbrake": "13"]
    
    @State private var selection = Set<String>()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        List(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(myList.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { item in
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Key:\t\t\(item)\t\t\t")
                    Text("Value:\t\(myList[item] ?? "")")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        
//        Text("Selection is:")
//        Text(selection)
//        Text("Selection is:\(selection)")
        
        
        Button(action: {
            print("Selection is:\(selection)")
        }) {
            Text("Get")
                .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted, `selection` contains only the selected keys, not values. To get the values, you need to use these keys to subscript your `myList` property like you do in the `HStack`. Here's an example:

```swift
Button(action: {
    let selectedValues = selection
        .compactMap { myList[$0] }
        .joined(separator: ", ")
    print("Selection is: \(selectedValues)")
}) {
    Text("Get")
        .padding()
}
```

I'm using `compactMap` here instead of `map` because the subscript returns an optional value, so this removes any nil values returned and gives us a list of non-optional strings.

Comment: Many thanks, that's really helpful! 

I had heard of map but had not really understood it so this has given me an opportunity to start to get my head around it.

I was also able to set a variable converted from the dict for the key via:

selectedKey = selection.map{return $0} 

which was useful to know.